# SQl select statement - putting Case inside the Where part

Tags: sql, case

Hello i am using Microsoft SQL server manager with visual studio and i kinda stuck with Select command i am trying to achive.

```
SELECT  ...               
FROM     ... 

WHERE  (t .companyID = @companyId) 
       AND (DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @start, r.date) >= 0) 
       AND (DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @end, r.date) <= 0) 
       // last row to add
       AND (CASE WHEN @status != 'show all' THEN r.poStatus = @status END)
```

The command working well but now i need to add the last row as well ( user can choose status and only rows with the choosen status will be shown or  if nothing choosen it will show all the rows - i got a vb code that  gives 'show all" value in that case ) 
so i wanna make an extra term that checks if the value is 'show all" skip this and  if not show the rows with the selected value but i cant find the right syntex to do this , if it possible ?

p.s  i seen it wasnt so clear what i ment by 'show all' is to show all of the table and only if its other then show all  use the WHERE part to select the right rows in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not doing it this way at all, and instead using an `IF/ELSE` block:

```
IF @Status = 'show all'
    BEGIN
        SELECT ...
        FROM ...
        WHERE   t .companyID = @companyId 
        AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @start, r.date) >= 0 
        AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @end, r.date) <= 0 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ..
        FROM    ...
        WHERE   t .companyID = @companyId 
        AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @start, r.date) >= 0 
        AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @end, r.date) <= 0 
        AND     r.poStatus = @status

    END
```

The reason for this is that unless you run your query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` the query will use a full table scan even if you pass a 
value for `@status' and`poStatus` is indexed which will not be optimal. The reason for choosing a table scan as opposed to an index seek is because at compilation time it doesn't know whether it should be returning all values for poStatus or just one.

If this is a stored procedure, or is passed through `sp_executesql` then the results could be worse still, at compile time the value will be known so the query
plan will be created based on the parameter value. However, each subsequent time it is run it will use the cached plan from this first run, and you could end with a suboptimal query plan.

For what it's worth, this predicate is not very good either, it is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable):

```
AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @start, r.date) >= 0 
AND     DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @end, r.date) <= 0
```

Because you are evaluating a function or `r.date` you cannot take advantage of any index on the column. It would be better written as:

```
AND     r.Date >= @Start
AND     r.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @End);
```

If you must do it all in one query for whatever reason, then as mentioned, you should use the query hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to ensure the query is compiled at runtime, and an appropriate plan can be chosen for the given value of `@Status`:

```
SELECT  ..
FROM    ...
WHERE   t .companyID = @companyId 
AND     r.Date >= @Start
AND     r.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @End);
AND     (r.poStatus = @status OR @Status = 'show all')
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the date bit.  I knew about the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` bit (I think DB2 _might_ be able to properly reduce/remove conditions for that pattern), but now I'm curious; what happens if you dump `@status` in a temp table (or CTE) and join to it?  Is it still subject to the same limitations?

Comment: This would always result in a table scan, the reason option recompile works is that it essentially allows short circuiting of the where clause. It can evaluate the constant expression `@status = 'show all'` at compile time and determine whether it is true or false. Although using a temporary table would create statistics on the table, the JOIN predicate would not be a constant that can be evaluated during compilation, so it would not help.

Comment: In my opinion using `IF/ELSE` is the best way to do this as it does not involve recompilation or suboptimal query plans, and with the ease of `Copy` and `Paste` duplicating almost identical blocks of code is not a lot of effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
(CASE WHEN @status != 'show all' THEN r.poStatus = @status END)
```

is equivalent to

```
IF @status = 'show all' THEN 
    ;// no additional conditions
ELSE // so @status != 'show all'
    r.poStatus = @status
END IF;
```

So you can put it in standard logical condition:

```
AND (@status = 'show all' OR (@status != 'show all' AND r.poStatus = @status))
```

Comment: Please explain your SQL statement. Don't give code-only answers.

Comment: Yes, this works, although SQL Server's optimizer seems to have some issues with this sort of condition.  Note that you don't need the `@status != 'show all'`, as that's guaranteed by the prior condition in the Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where r.poStatus = 
    Case When @Status != 'Show all' Then @status 
         Else r.poStatus End
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: If `@Status` was 'show all' then the result of the case statement would be `NULL` so `r.PoStatus = NULL` would evaluate to `NULL` and no rows would be returned.

Comment: I know that but I just write the correct format of the query in the question not the final answer. @GarethD

Comment: Hi when its show all it takes empy value and aint showing anything

Comment: @user3603579c as I reply to GarethD I just change your query to it's right format. You should tell me more about your logic so I can answer more efficient.

Comment: @MeysamTolouee - There's no reason to **not** give a working answer, instead of just a supposed "framework".

Comment: Yes, this works.  However, in almost all instances, `CASE` should be avoided everywhere except the `SELECT` list, as it can make it difficult for optimizers to use indices (read, query may be slow).

Answer (score 1):

Try avoid CASE and use boolean condition instead.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE (t .companyID = @companyId) AND (DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @start, r.date) >= 0)
AND (DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, @end, r.date) <= 0)
AND (@status = 'show all' OR r.poStatus = @status);
```

Comment: Yes, this works (and I'd avoid `CASE` in general too), but the optimizer for SQL Server (and possibly some other RDBMSs) doesn't seem to like this format; it tends to require full table scans (will not be as performant).  Also, when answering questions, look to see if there's any _other_ portion you can improve.  In this case, the searches on `r.date` won't be able to use an index, due to the use of that function; if you query it in a range (See Gareth's answer), the query can be much faster.